# Reading space-separated integers efficiently

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, user-input

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
>>> input_list = list(map(int, input().split()))
13 4 56 75 22 3
>>> input_list
[13, 4, 56, 75, 22, 3]
```

Comment: Are you having a particular performance problem? It's 31 characters; how much were you hoping to shave off?

Comment: You could use a list comp perhaps, but it won't make (much) difference here. `[int(i) for i in input().split()]`

Comment: `map(int, input().split())` already returns a list, when you put `list()` around it you copy the whole thing over again, so just using the map function would probably make it faster.

Comment: @MikeP. not in [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) it doesn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oops sorry, I'm working in 2.7 didn't see that in the title.

Comment: [Read Guildo's loop optimization tales](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/)

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I'm not trying to reduce the number of characters.
Since split() itself goes through the input string once and then the map() has to go through the list after that I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I gather you are concerned about memory use and you want to avoid creating a temporary list. Unfortunately Python doesn't have an iterator version of string.split (AFAIK), but you can use re.finditer:

```
[int(match.group(0)) for match in re.finditer(r'\w+', input())]
```

But unless your input is many megabytes long there's really no need to worry about memory and complicate your code like this.

Comment: I just started working on my first data science project. So I'm looking at ways to reduce execution time.